# Insert data into an array just updating the data that already exists with the same key/value

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

I'm developing a front of a webapp for deliveries and on this screen I put the google map so that the company owner can see the route of their motoboys in real-time. So far so good, the map was simple to implement, but the problem itself is in the definition of map markers, which are received from an app running on the motoboy's cell phone via websocket. From there, an array of objects is sent with the data: latitude, longitude and name of each motoboy.

The problem is that each motoboy sends a location separately and as I'm storing it in a state to be able to make an Array.map and generate the Markers, it breaks, because every new data that arrives it overwrites the old one.

I tried to perform some methods with Array.push(), Array.concat() etc... But the data ends up duplicating, as shown in the example image:
[image: console.log]

The result of this image was from some tests I was doing.

This is now the code I'm trying to implement

State that I use to store the data:

```
const [motoboysCoords, setMotoboysCoords] = useState<CoordsProps[]>([]);
```

Excerpt that I listen to via websocket and receive data from apps on delivery people's cell phones

```
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(Environment.BASE_URL_SERVER);
        socket.on('receivedPosition', (msg: LocationProps) => {
            setMotoboysCoords([]);
            setMotoboysCoords(oldCoords => oldCoords.concat(msg.localization));
        });
    }, [motoboysCoords]);
```

In this case I wanted to receive the new data, put them in the array keeping the old data in case there is already with the same name.

Code snippet inside the GoogleMap component where I make the Array.map():

```
{motoboysCoords.map((item, index) => (
                        <Marker
                            key={index}
                            position={{
                                lat: Number(item.lat),
                                lng: Number(item.long)
                            }}
                        />
                    ))}
```

So far I've tried to fill my state using Array.push() and .concat(), but I couldn't create a logic that replaces my previous data and adds the new data validating by the object's name key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update just one item in the array you will first have to find it and replace it.
Easiest way I could come up with is, based on the assumption that `msg.localization` is of type `CoordsProps`

```
socket.on('receivedPosition', (msg: LocationProps) => {
            setMotoboysCoords(oldCoords => [...oldCoords.filter(c => c.name !== msg.localization.name), msg.localization]);
        });
```

For extra points and better scaling you could change the state to just a object using the name or a id as key to make updates easier. Going from object to array in the render function is rather simple.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys